# Check which windows update will be installed

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I manage a server windows 2012 which was not updated for approximately 2 years, to estimate the impact for a global update, I would like to know how many updates and which ones will be installed next time I activate windows update, and the size of the global updates that will be downloaded.

How can do it ? (in preference, by powershell because of a core server)

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Windows Update PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc), then run `Get-WUList`, it will take a while but will show you the required updates with their size. You can then use `Get-WUInstall` to download and install them.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I need. But have you ever use it ? I unzipped it in %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules, launch import-module PSWindowsUpdate, execute Get-WUList, and I get the prompt without any return.

Comment: I use it every month, are you running it elevated?

Comment: I just try elevated, same result (..no result :(  )

Comment: Try Get-WULIST `-verbose`, `-debuger` or -`IsInstalled` or maybe `-MicrosoftUpdate`.

Comment: It works... be careful to not launch the script from %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules....